# Is there a way to simplify S3 access log lines?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The problem is, log files are too big for mining. 
(assume that daily requests are nearly 100m )

I'm wondering maybe there is a way to simplify request lines. I don't need all bucket field values.

eg line:

```
314423094967345b38a76d76d78c678b4 bucket_name [14/Nov/2010:13:53:59 +0000] 11.22.33.44 Anonymous 3E43423453A12F47 REST.GET.OBJECT s3browser/2.4.5/s3browser-portable-2-4-5.exe "GET /s3browser/2.4.5/s3browser-portable-2-4-5.exe HTTP/1.1" 200 - 289897 289897 50 44 "http://s3browser.com/download.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.517.44 Safari/534.7" -
```

I couldn't find any information about reducing the number of fileds in bucket format.

I only need Time, Remote IP, Key, Referrer, Bytes Sent, Object Size and User-Agent.

Any one got any idea about that?

Also welcome for any other ideas about mining these big files in a short time periods.

Thanks.

Comment: Use an ETL process that will preprocess all the logs before you use them for data mining. Kettle is an application that can be used for this or you can roll your own solution.

Comment: There are lots of kettle application. Which one do you prefer? I'm gonna check it asap.

Comment: In this case I am talking about this: http://kettle.pentaho.com/ Its a GUI that will allow you to build ETL jobs to process/convert data.